# Lumia 520 restart problem

Tags: lumia-520

My Lumia 520 keeps restarting every minute. I have taken the phone to Microsoft Store but my problem was not solved, the people there told me the phone problem was not solved. How can I fix it?

Comment: I fond the solution for this because of heavy usage apps and other things this will happen Better you can buy new mobile enjoy your experiences

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a real issue now doesn't it? First off have you tried these things:

- Removing SIM
- Soft Reset before the reset

If you have, this may be a bug on their side. I recommend factory resetting it. If this does not fix anything, your OS was corrupted. Simple go into your phone provider and explain the issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: All those steps I try it's not working for me